# Styles do not applied with default "open=true" property with first start of "react-native-drawer"

Tags: react-native

Drawer settings:

```
<Drawer
  open={true}
  tapToClose={true}
  initializeOpen={true}
  tweenDuration={100}
  disabled={false}
  type="overlay"
  content={<[component name] />}
  tapToClose={true}
  openDrawerOffset={0.2}
  panOpenMask={0.05}
  panCloseMask={0.2}
  closedDrawerOffset={-2}
  tweenHandler={(ratio) => (
    { main: { opacity: 1 },
    mainOverlay: { opacity: ratio / 2, backgroundColor: 'black',}
    })}
  styles={{
  drawer: {shadowColor: 'black', shadowOpacity: 0.8, shadowRadius: 2,
                  elevation: 20}, //Supported on Android 5.0+ only
  main: {paddingLeft: 2}
  }}
  >
```

### Environment

react-native-drawer version: 2.3.0

React Native version: 0.42.3

Platform(s) (iOS, Android, or both?): both

Device info Simulator/Device? - Simulator Android 4.1 (API16) / 7.1.1 (API25), Simulator iOS 10.2 / iOS 8.1

OS version? - MacOS 10.12.3

Debug/Release? - Debug

---

**BUT** "mainOverlay: { ..., **backgroundColor:  'black**',} **does not applied** with first start:

[image: backgroundColor white]

After close and open drawer again it looks as expected with black background color:

[image: backgroundColor black]

Maybe someone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I searched some previous issues on 'react-native-drawer' for some background related problem during which I stumbled upon this solution which works fine for me .

Set your styles prop of Drawer component to

`styles={
    mainOverlay: {
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        opacity: 0,
    }
}`

&

Set tweenHandler prop of Drawer component to

`tweenHandler={(ratio) => ({
    mainOverlay: {
        opacity: ratio / 2
    }
})`